# Get image from Google Cloud Storage in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get an image in my `App Engine` backend and every time I try to get it I get the following error

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
 {
   "code": 503,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "global",
       "message": "java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.",
       "reason": "backendError"
     }
   ],
   "message": "java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information."
 }
```

Now it was my understanding that when making a request from App Engine backend that the `Application Default Credentials` was sufficient enough to do it.

> The Application Default Credentials provide a simple way to get
>   authorization credentials for use in calling Google APIs.
>
> They are best suited for cases when the call needs to have the same
>   identity and authorization level for the application independent of
>   the user. This is the recommended approach to authorize calls to
>   Google Cloud APIs, particularly when you're building an application
>   that is deployed to Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine virtual
>   machines.

taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)

This is how I am trying to get the image using the `Java API`

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

if(credential.createScopedRequired()){
   credential = credential.createScoped(StorageScopes.all());
}

Storage.Builder storageBuilder = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport,new JacksonFactory(),credential);
Storage storage = storageBuilder.build();

Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get("myBucket", name);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(false);
getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);

byte[] oldImageData = out.toByteArray();
out.close();

ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(oldImageData);
Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(width, height);

return imagesService.applyTransform(resize, oldImage);
```

am I just using the credentials wrong or can I not use the application default credentials?

Comment: As I understand it works if you are using internal links `gs://` vs external links

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your Google Cloud Storage data from App Engine. You should be using the [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/)

[Github Project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client)